# Difference between First Order Logic and Predicate Calculus

Tags: first-order-logic

I see the two used interchangeably. Is one the subset of the other or are they both the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First-order logic and first-order predicate calculus are the same thing, which is exactly why the terms are used interchangeably. See, for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic):

> First-order logic [...] is also known as first-order predicate calculus, the lower predicate calculus, quantification theory, and predicate logic.